# Why Motzi Shabbath?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, motzei-shabbos

Where does the phrase Motzi Shabbath come from? Grammatically i don't understand how it works.

Motzi means the bringing forth-er, or the bringing-out-er right? Ha-motzi lechem min ha-aretz, "the one who brings forth/out bread from the earth" Is it trying to say that Shabbath has been brought out?

Comment: it should be motza'ei shabbat I think

Comment: Ah, well everyone here keeps saying "motzi shabbos" or "motzi shabbath," hence my confusion

Comment: @Aaron Yes, in common speech we tend to slur words or just say them wrong. Like "Shkoyach" instead of "yi-yasher kochacha"

Comment: Seems that people named Aaron are very interested in this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35131/1713. Is this a dupe?

Comment: @Daniel It's a bit eery that the person who asked the same question is also named Aaron. But that person is not me ;) So yeah it looks like a dupe, although i appreciate having the answers here as they provide the nekkudoth for proepr pronunciation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term is not מוֹצִיא שַׁבָּת‎ (Motzi Shabbat) but rather מוֹצָאֵי שַׁבָּת‎ (Motzaei Shabbat).

Both words comes from the *shoresh* י.צ.א.‏ which has to do with going out. מוֹצִיא is a verb in the הפעיל (causative) binyan. It means "cause to go out" or more concisely, "bring out." I am not entirely sure of the grammatical form of מוֹצָאֵי but it appears to me to be a gerund: "the going out of Shabbat"; [more information is available on the phrase](/q/35131).

Motzaei Shabbat is the time when Shabbat "goes out."

Comment: מוצאי is the plural of מוצא, such as מוצא שפתיך תשמור ועשית (this week's parsha) or מוצא שפתיה לנדריה or מוצא פי ה יחיה האדם

Comment: @DoubleAA Ok, so that makes מוצאי שבת "the things that go out of Shabbat." That makes me want a better answer to [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35131/1713)

Comment: @Daniel Same here. The term doesn't fit right to me, i'm glad to know what the proper term is, of Motzaei, but even Motzaei doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: @Aaron After thinking about it a bit, I do kind of feel like I understand it a bit. Think about the feeling of Saturday night. It has a different kind of feeling from the rest of the week. It's not Shabbat anymore, but there is a bit of the feeling of Shabbat left over. You're probably still wearing your Shabbat clothes and you have a melaveh malkah. Maybe that feeling is what goes out of Shabbat?

Comment: I'll see if I can research the use of the plural. I think it may have some connection to the *Melava Malka* idea, i.e. a metaphoric reference to escorting the Shabbat "Queen", and the "going out" refers, somehow, to OUR (the people) going out to escort her. Just a "crazy" thought.

Comment: @Daniel i can see your point...But something about this seems a bit off either way.

Comment: Related question (as I may have an idea) - Is the Hebrew root form for the verbs "to go out" and "to find" the same or different root forms?

Comment: @DanF Different. To find is מ.צ.א

Comment: @Daniel Sorry ... The 2nd part of your comment may have had Hebrew letters that didn't appear correctly. Can you retry, or better, use transliteration showing the difference in the two root forms?

Comment: @DanF They appear correctly to me. Go out is Y-Tz-A, find is M-Tz-A

Comment: @Daniel Ah. OK. I suspected that. I thought perhaps, that *Motza'ei Shabbat* might have a hint that it conveys blessing in the week that you "find". But, that idea doesn't mesh, here. Hmmm... I'll have to ask my rav for insights, though I may stump him on this one ;-)